Is the warranty implying the lifetime of the product legally?
Let's say I buy a TV with a 2-year warranty, does this legally imply I'm agreeing the lifetime of the TV is just 2 years? so if it least for longer than that, it's just luck of mine, and the maker can have a "planned obsolescence" after the warranty legally just like an unsubscribed service?
I read through other questions, I saw others mentioned the "reasonable time", so does the warranty means the reasonable time? If not, why are they don't align?

What? How did you arrive at this conclusion?

I am just wondering why we have a different "warranty time" and  "reasonable time" if the result is either the seller fixes it(non-human damage within "reasonable time") or the consumer takes the responsibility(excess "reasonable time").
Why not just have a signal cutoff date of the responsibility, for me, the time excesses warranty but within "reasonable time" seems just a phantom right of the consumer since it usually takes impractical effort to let the seller fix the problem for you.

@ctct In countries where you have rights it is usually no problem.

No, the two year warranty says that someone will fix the problem for two years.
How long the product lasts, depends on the design, your good / bad luck getting a product that has been built better / less good than the average, and your usage - a washing machine used 12 hours a day will not last as long as one used once a week.
The manufacturer calculates the time - two years here - by wanting customers buy more items because of the long warranty, and on the other hand not wanting to have to pay out for too many repairs. Basically, “two years warranty” tells you the manufacturer doesn’t expect many products to break in that time.
In countries with strong consumer rights (EU, UK, Australia) “warranty” is what the manufacturer gives you, but sellers have to fix problems for “a reasonable time”. And if your washing machine breaks after two years and one week, the manufacturer may fix it if they think a good reputation is worth more than the cost of a repair.

2 years is the legally required period in the EU for most products, but there are some with more or less.

Note that warranties sometimes only cover problems/defects due to the situation that present at the time of sale. In that case a long warranty becomes increasingly hard to enforce since you have to prove that the problem isn't caused by improper user acts after sale.

Short manufacturer warranties also foster a secondary market for "extended" warranties.

I once bought a product with a 24 Watt power supply and 23 Watt power consumption. That will break. The only time I ever bought extended warranty. They gave me a new product including two years free extended warranty. I thought if they keep breaking I’m set for life.
